# How would I completely remove a domain from webs?

Tags: dns, nameserver

I have registered a domain with 1&1.co.uk about 2 months ago. I changed the nameservers to the ones that webs told me to (ns1.webs.com, ns2.webs.com) so that I could publish my webs website to my custom domain. It was all working fine.

What threw everything out is that yesterday, when I wanted to start using Weebly, I changed the nameservers in 1&1 to weebly's and waited to the changes to propagate through the internet. 1&1 said that the changes had been made but when I publish changes from weebly, they don't actually show but changes in webs do.

Is there anything that I have missed in doing this process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't followed up this post http://kb.weebly.com/domain-registrar.html , take a look and give it a try again.

Comment: Yes I followed this but thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it your problem solved now?